# Absolute Block Nested in Relative Block Appears Lower in IE8

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-8, cross-browser, css-position

Ugh. I really, really hate cross-browser compatibility... I'm working on a Wordpress site for a client to create a popup box that appears just below the item I'm hovering over (using a custom shortcode). I have top set to 16px, and it works fine in Firefox. However, in IE8, it appears a lot further down. Even if I set top to "0", it still appears BELOW the containing blog, instead of at the top of it.

I also have a related issue, in that the font size in IE8 is about 2 pixels smaller. There is a `<sup></sup>` tag before this, as well, but removing it doesn't change much--the font size is still smaller in IE8.

Here is the page:

http://www.medicalmarcom.com/services/

Every question mark along the left side has a popup that appears when hovering over it (kinda like a tooltip). I need to make it work in FF, IE, Safari, and Chrome. The only one it doesn't work in is IE. Thankfully, he didn't mention IE6, so I'm not worrying about it unless he singles it out.

Here is the HTML:

```
<span class="questions"><sup>(
<div class="popup_content"><span class="popup">?</span>
<div class="popup_inside" style="display: none;">We’ll ask questions to understand your business, objectives, competitive situation, and positioning statement.<br />

<a href="http://www.medicalmarcom.com/services/medical-device-marketing-discovery/"><span style="color:#15398c"><em>Read More >>></em></span></a></div>
</div>
)</sup></span>
```

CSS:

```
.popup_content {
    display: inline;
    position: relative;
}
.popup_inside {
    background-color: #FFF;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    text-align: left;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #000;
    width: 300px;
    padding: 2px;
    line-height: 1.5;
    left: 0;
    top: 16px;
    z-index: 1001;
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
}
.popup {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1000;
}
```

Comment: Changing the font-size and top values seemed to bring it in line with FF for me.  Are you sure changing the top value doesn't fix it?

Comment: There's got to be something else going on here... Top: 0 should position the top of the box at the top of the parent container, not appear just below it. I didn't think about trying to use !important, but I don't even know if it would work... and I don't think its a good idea. Changing the top and font-size values changes it for all browsers. If I bring it higher up in IE, it messes with how it looks in the other browsers.

I don't think the site I'm working on uses reset.css... If it was it might just fix the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, this is due to how ie8 is rendering the sup tag, I believe. It considers its baseline the same as the rest of the text, rather than above it. If you want to do this with just css, I'd consider rolling your own superscript class.

[Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tARSK/) of something that seemed to work for me.

As an alternative solution, it seems to be rendering correctly in IE7, you could force IE8 into IE7 Compatibility Mode. Drop this line at the top of your `<head>`. I don't know what this will do to IE9, but it's worth a shot.

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE7" />
```

Comment: Hmm... I did try removing the sup tag, but it didn't seem to do anything. Perhaps, though, I had something else in there that was messing with it.

In .questions, though, shouldn't it be position: relative? I'll try both.

Comment: Okay, that's a lot close now. This fixed the issue of the font size being smaller in IE. It also seems that the popup is a little closer. There's got to be something else, though, so I'll dig around a bit more. I may not have emulated everything exactly the same as what you said in jsFiddle. Of note, I removed sup and added the new values to .questions; I set it to relative instead of absolute, though, because absolute pushed the (?) too far to the right.